# "Oбнулить" и "настраивать на нуль"

Tags: значения, выбор-слова

На викисловаре есть [два перевода английского глагола zero](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zero#Translations_4). Суть "обнулить" и "настраивать на нуль". Насколько я вижу, "настраивать на нуль" гораздо реже чем "обнулить", но я <strike>об</strike> **В** этом не полностью уверен. А есть между этими двумя выражениями семантическая разница?

Comment: Если речь о русском языке, то разница может быть, но для английского zero (verb) все, что я посмотрел в англ. словарях сводится к значению "Adjust (an instrument) to zero" - т.е.одно конкретное значение. Мне кажется надо разделять английское слово и предлагаемые русские термины, т.к. в русском ОБНУЛИТЬ может означать не только zero, но и что-то вроде clear, erase, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Настраивать на нуль" (или на "ноль") - это узкоспециальный инженерный термин, можно настраивать на нуль, например, микрометр, но нельзя настроить на нуль результаты прошлого месяца - а обнулить можно.

`Обнулить` ближе к отменить, сделать нерелевантным (это помимо, разумеется, основного значения - "присвоить нуль"), `настроить на нуль` - откалибровать, сбросив нестандартные настройки.

Comment: При пограммированием можно настраивать на нуль переменную или процессорный регистр, а обнулить их нельзя. Я правильно понял?

Comment: *Т.е.* `int x = 0;`

Comment: _Обнулить_ регистры можно всегда, принудительно записав в них нули. _Настройка_ же на нуль (напр. при калибровке прибора) обычно связана с установкой максимально близкого к нулю значения измеряемой величины в условиях, когда нуль _не является крайним_ положением.

Comment: @Wilson в программировании как раз переменные обнуляют )

Comment: @Wilson It's the other way round: "обнулить" переменную, регистр, буфер, массив. "Настраивать" is "to tune", so it's basically about calibrating a measurement instrument, so that its '0' corresponds to real 0 (volts, amps, kilos, etc).

Answer (score 2):

*"Настраивать на нуль"* - это, прежде всего, *"настраивать"*. Если про некоторую деятельность можно сказать *"настраивать"*, а результатом этой деятельности должен быть нуль - то про эту деятельность можно сказать *"настраивать на нуль"*.

*Обнулить* - более общее понятие.

Answer (score 2):

We don't use "настраивать на ноль" anymore, I doubt that I even heard this in my life. Обнулить - it's like reset (for example: обнулить счёт (reset score)), настраивать на ноль - it's more like technical (for example: настроить электрическую волну на ноль (configure electrical wave on zero)).

Comment: when it comes to word usage quite often "we don't use" is quite a bold statement - the universe of word usage is quite huge, there are lot of things not to forget about - professional communities, slang etc.

Comment: @shabunc On the other hand it's too easy to declare some sentence being just a result of a single man or an isolated event mistake/miscommunication as "it's a slang or a specific area usage". As an engineer I also never heard of "настраивать на нуль" being used as "zeroing" and because it does sound awkward that way (simply because "настраивать" itself has very different connotation) I seriously doubt it was *ever* widely used like that.

Comment: @shabunc when people say about stopping using certain words it not means that literally no one is using it - the meaning is about general between people, conversation, frequency. And nowadays you have internet with this infinite amount of information so if you watching movies, reading stories, documentation, books and after few years of it you hear word that you can't recognize it can be easily considered as outdated because language is evolving.

Comment: @turik97 I'd rather wonder where the authors of the linked wiktionary page got their translation (use of "нуль" suggest they *might* indeed find something like that in older papers. On the other hand the chances that it's just another "bad translation" are also not zero. I'm afraid this is generally pointless discussion w/o actually having some relevant citations/references (and even with them it would remain questionable - i.e. just one or two people writing something weird do not constitute a language/slang yet).

Comment: @seven-phases-max yes and because of that I gave answer where I mentioned outdating so TC would know about actual situation and then I gave relevant example of meaning and difference between these words. I think sometimes there must be information from people's first mouth and not only when guys giving vocabulary meaning of word without knowing how actually it  works and when.

Answer (score 0):

*Обнулить* предполагает, что есть какое-то значение, которое делается равным нулю. Т.е. некое значение существует до операции ОБНУЛЕНИЯ.

*Настроить на ноль* - может быть и до существования значения, до эксплуатации. Т.е. что-либо выставляется на ноль (может быть что угодно).